# Rails - send email on button click

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

rails 4.1.1

I have an OrdersController and on the orders show action I have...

orders_controller.rb

```
def show
  @order = Order.find(params[:id])
  @client = Client.find(@order.client_id)

  if request.post?
    OrderMailer.order_send(@client, @order).deliver
    flash[:notice] = 'Order details sent!'
    redirect_to order_path(@order.id)
  end
end
```

Then on the view I have...

(show.haml)

```
= button_to "Send", @order
```

If I take the "OrderMailer" out of the if statement and visit the show/ order page, the email gets sent repeatedly until I close the dev server so I know the mailer part sends/ works ok.

I am just unsure how to tie the button click/send email together? I need a route but not sure how to tie it together if I already have a route for the orders/show page?

routes.rb

```
resources :orders, :path => 'orders'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, with help of @steel here is code.

routes.rb(changed start to symbol)

```
get :send_order_mail, to: 'orders#send_order_mail', as: :send_order_mail
```

orders_controller.rb

```
def send_order_mail
  @order = Order.find(params[:id])
  @client = Customer.find(@order.client_id)

  OrderMailer.order_send(@order, @client).deliver
  flash[:notice] = "Order has been sent."
  redirect_to order_path(@order.id)
end
```

orders/show.html.erb has the link on it.

```
<%= link_to "Send Order by email", :controller => "orders", :action => "send_order_mail", :id => @order.id %>
```

mailers/order_mailer.rb

```
class OrderMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  add_template_helper(OrdersHelper)

  default from: "mail@example.com"

  def order_send(order, client)
    @order = order
    @client = client
    mail(to: "#{@client.email}", subject: "Your subject")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure how to make your current method work, but there are several ways to do this. Here's one way I've used:

Set up your controller action:

```
orders_controller.rb

def send_order_mail
  @parameters = Model.get_parameters
  OrderMailer.name_of_action(@parameters).deliver
  # redirect code here
end
```

Set up your route:

```
get send_order_mail, to: 'orders_controller#send_order_mail', as: :send_order_mail
```

Then make your link.

```
link_to 'Send mail', send_order_mail_path, class: "big-button"
```

Comment: Thanks for replay @steel. Adding that route gives me an error when starting dev server "undefined local variable or method `send_order_mail' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper:0x00000006472178> (NameError)"?

Comment: Did you define it in your orders_controller?

Comment: Yes I did.I now have route as 'get 'orders/:id', to: 'orders_controller#send_order_mail', as: :send_order_mail' but clicking the "Send" link does nothing.

Comment: This code has worked for me in my app, so something is going wrong in your implementation I suspect. Happy to look at a gist or git of your code.

Comment: @polarcare are you using 'send_order_mail' in your button's view instead of 'send_order_mail_path'? If so use 'send_order_mail_path' to fix the problem.